# How to get all classes in a Namespace using Reflection in a WP8.1 App?

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have read several posts about how to get Classes using reflection even there are different examples in StackOverflow but none of them is related to this Version of WP or Windows and if you try those codes no of them works. This is the last one that I tried:

```
string @namespace = "Supernova.Entities";

var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == @namespace)
    .ToList();

types.ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Name.GetType()));
```

I hope someone could give me an idea because when I tried something like that VS always told me: 'System.Reflection.Assembly' does not contain a definition for 'GetExecutingAssembly'.

I'm trying to use this but I'm not sure how to change it.
[Reflection WinRT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302(v=VS.85).aspx#reflection)

This is my class:

```
namespace Supernova.Entities
{
    public class profile
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class bloodResults
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int idbloodresult { get; set; }
        public double result { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Later I want to create each of my entities using Reflection with a method like this one:

```
public static async void CreateDatabase()
{
   var profile = await ConnectionDb().CreateTableAsync<profile>();
   var bloodresults = await ConnectionDb().CreateTableAsync<bloodResults>();
}
```

Why am I trying to do this? Because this is not my first time using SQLite and I'd like to create a standard method to make my work easier. Thanks for your worthy knowledge.

Comment: Side note: since namespaces have no formal relation to assemblies (i.e. unlike Java) you can't really "get all classes in a Namespace" as this set is not bound by anything... Also you likely mean "... from this assembly in this namespace".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetExecutingAssembly` is not available in WinRT, but you can use `typeof(AClassInYourAssembly).GetTypeInfo().Assembly` instead.

```
    string @namespace = "Supernova.Entities";
    var assembly = typeof(YourClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    var types = assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.GetTypeInfo().IsClass && t.Namespace == @namespace)
        .ToList();

    types.ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Name));
```

Comment: But what should I modify the last code? Because I don't got how to modify it. Sorry because I'm really new with WP8.1, last code I used on WP8 and I didn't have any problem.

Comment: @FANM, see my updated answer. BTW, `t.Name.GetType()` will always be String, so it's probably not what you want...

Comment: If you want I have updated my post to show what I'm looking. Thanks for your valuable time and help.